# OnMouseOver() don't change the Href property with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href, onmouseover

I have this link in my web that I would like to change with JavaScript. For some reason, I can change its "Display" property but I can't change its "href" property.

Here it goes:

Line with the script

```
<li style="width:15%; text-align:center;" onMouseOver="B1();"><a href="">ADMINISTRACION</a></li>
```

Line with the link to be changed

```
<li id="A1" style="width:10%; text-align:center; display:none;"><a href="">A1</a></li>
```

Function with the JavaScript

```
function B1(){
            document.getElementById("A1").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("A1").href="local.php";
            document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML="Locales";}
```

The display and innerHTML properties work fine. But it doesn't recognizes the element as a link anymore. Is there a problem with my code? Or maybe this event doesn't work with this property?

Thanx in advantage!

Comment: why do you want to set href on li tag? If your purpose is to save it in <li> then set a  data attribute and save the data there.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_setattribute2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing to the li-element, which has no href attribute.
select the anchor under your li first:

```
document.getElementById("A1").getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href="local.php";
```

Comment: Thanx bro!! Really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your syntax as follows. Refer [W3schools sample](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) that explains how to modify attributes in JavaScript.

document.getElementById("A1").setAttribute("href", "local.php");